# How to extend Shopware 6 plugin controller

Tags: symfony, shopware

I'm new to Shopware 6

A Other plugin needs to be extended.
When I write in the service.xml of a Oter plugin

```
<service id="OterPlugin\Storefront\Controller\OterPluginController" class="MyPlugin\Storefront\Controller\MyPluginController" public="true"> 
...
</service>
```

My plugin controller works. But I need to leave the Oter plugin unchanged.

How can I make My plugin controller work without changing the Other plugin?

I would be very grateful for a code example of how to register the override in the plugin (config.xml, service.xml, or maybe controller.xml)

Comment: Someone down-voted your question, probably because it's hard to understand. Please try to make it more clear by editing your question. Thanks.

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 3):

It is not 100% clear to me, what are you trying to achieve here, but in general, the overriding can be done using the decorator pattern. You can find out, how to do that, in the official Symfony documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html (Shopware 6 is based on the Symfony framework). I also have a practical example of that on my blog here:
https://shopwarian.com/solved-shopware-6-sitemap-generates-urls-with-http-instead-of-https/.